# Obtaining blob jp2 format from PerlMagick?

Tags: perl, image-processing

I tried to convert png files withing a script using Image::Magick but it seems that it does not work for me (although I have an image in the $file, after the ImageToBlob command is executed, I have an empty blob):

```
my $image = $file->ImageToBlob(magick => 'jp2', quality => 90);
```

Can anyone tell me what's the correct format to obtain a jpeg2000 file? It works with other parameters for magick => 'png' / magick=>'jpg';

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the JPEG2000 delegate installed, check by typing

```
identify -version
```

or

```
configure -list delegates | grep -i delegates
```